# Need delay after my comment

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please suggest the way to delay of 5 seconds after my comment just below location.href = url;

I have tried setTimeout and setInterval but it is not behaving correctly in all browsers.
I have also tried sleep as implemented below:

```
            function sleep(milliseconds) {
                var start = new Date().getTime();
                for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
                    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
                      break;
                     }
                  }
                }
                console.log(new Date());
                console.log('Deleting AdHoc...');
                sleep(6000);
                console.log(new Date());
```

But this is also not working always and also not elegant.

```
function xToolbar(url, target, name, options, message, height, width) {
if (message == '') {
    ok = true
} else {
    ok = confirm(message);
}
if (ok == true) {
    if (target == 'window') {
        if (height != '') {
            myTop = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 10);
            myLeft = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
            options = 'height=' + height + ',width=' + width + ',top=' + myTop + ',left=' + myLeft + ',' + options;
        }
        var popup = window.open('', "Loader", options);
        var baseUrls = location.href.split("/")
        var baseUrl = baseUrls[0] + "/" + baseUrls[1] + "/" + baseUrls[2] + "/" + baseUrls[3] + "/" + baseUrls[4]
        popup.document.writeln('<!--fix for ie7-->')
        popup.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html>')
        popup.document.writeln('<html><head><style>')
        popup.document.writeln('body, html {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;background:#fff;color:#333;font:Normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;}')
        popup.document.writeln('h5 {font-weight:normal; font-size:14px;margin:0 0 10px 0;}')
        popup.document.writeln('#outer {width:100%;height:90%;position:relative;}')
        popup.document.writeln('#outer[id]{display:table;position: static;}')
        popup.document.writeln('#middle {position:absolute;top:50%;width: 100%;text-align:center;}')
        popup.document.writeln('#middle[id] {display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width: 100%;position: static;}')
        popup.document.writeln('#inner {position:relative;top:-50%}')
        popup.document.writeln('</style></head><body>')
        popup.document.writeln('<div id="outer"><div id="middle"><div id="inner"><h5>Processing your request</h5>')
        popup.document.writeln('<img src="' + baseUrl + '/images/toolbar/loader_fan.gif" id="loader" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle"/></div></div></div>')
        popup.document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript">')
        popup.document.writeln('function load(){')
        popup.document.writeln('location.href = "' + baseUrl + "/" + url.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\') + '";')
        popup.document.writeln('loader.setAttribute("src","' + baseUrl + '/images/toolbar/loader_fan.gif");};')
        popup.document.writeln('</script>')
        popup.document.writeln('</body></html>')
        popup.document.close();
        popup.load();
    } else {
        if (target == 'frame') {
            url += '{amp}EXECUTE_TEMPLATE=$';
            var frame = document.getElementById(name);
            frame.src = url;
        } else {
            location.href = url;
            // Comment : Please put here some code to delay by 5 seconds
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to delay the comment, or delay the going to the new location.href?

Comment: after setting a location.href, the page is going to change, so no matter what timeout you give, it is not going to execute as the code is no longer going to be there. Or are you meaning to delay the location change?

Comment: `document.writeln` uses `document.write`, which should be avoided (see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29)). Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: Also how were you using setTimeout?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have to close the page and refresh the page from where a new window/tab opened...

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am currently using sleep function - removed setInterval. If possible please let me know the most suitable code piece to be used either by setTimeout/setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are wanting to delay the page change then use setTimeout, you say you have tried using setTimeout, but without you showing us how you used it I am going to assume you used it wrong

```
...
else {
   setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.href=url;
   },5000);
}
```

If you are needing to refresh the opener page, and if the popup is of the same domain, then you can set a timer on the container window

```
   ...
   else {
      var opener = window.opener;
      if(opener !== null){
         opener.setTimeout(function(){
            opener.location.href=url;
         },5000);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to load after a given delay, use setTimeout() before the location.href link. As mentioned by Patrick, it will not be executed after it goes to other page.

Comment: I need to call window.close() and window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href in setTimeout. Could you please write the snippet ?

Comment: You can call another function like setTimeout(closeandopenwindow(), 6000); and include your code in the closeandopenwindow() function seperately.